# what to do if nuget-package requires deprecated dependency?

Tags: nuget

I need to get rid of deprecated nuget packages, by replacing them with new versions or replacements.

But what do I do, if another non-deprecated packages has a dependency to a deprecated one?

e.g. this package "https://www.nuget.org/packages/dbup-sqlserver/#dependencies-body-tab"
has a dependency to "Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication", which is deprecated.

Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication needs to be replaces by "Azure.Identity", but when I do this, the other package will have a missing dependency...

Answer (score 0):

You should install in your solution the deprecated dependency first at all and after that, you could install the nuget package which contains in its dependencies the deprecated one I mentioned.
It solves the problem and your solution will run flawlessly.